# How to take unique count of one attribute and set to the other

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures

I am getting object data in the following form.

```
data :  Object {ELEMENTID: "ELE1", ELEMENTNAME: "EME1", ELE: "Yes"}
    Object {ELEMENTID: "ELE1", ELEMENTNAME: "EME1", ELE: "Yes"}
    Object {ELEMENTID: "ELE2", ELEMENTNAME: "EME1", ELE: "Yes"}
    Object {ELEMENTID: "ELE3", ELEMENTNAME: "EME1", ELE: "Yes"}
    Object {ELEMENTID: "ELE1", ELEMENTNAME: "EME1", ELE: "Yes"}
    Object {ELEMENTID: "ELE3", ELEMENTNAME: "EME1", ELE: "Yes"}
    Object {ELEMENTID: "ELE3", ELEMENTNAME: "EME1", ELE: "Yes"}
    Object {ELEMENTID: "ELE2", ELEMENTNAME: "EME1", ELE: "Yes"}
```

Now I want to change my data into the following form.

```
data : object {ELEMENTID: "ELE1: ELEMENTNAME: 3, ELE : "Yes"}
       object {ELEMENTID: "ELE2: ELEMENTNAME: 2, ELE : "Yes"}
       object {ELEMENTID: "ELE3: ELEMENTNAME: 3, ELE : "Yes"}
```

I am taking the unique count of STU and placing into SUB and in STU placing only unique values. I am able to take unique count of STU but how to place in attribute in SUB

Can any one help me how to proceed.

Comment: Please tag your questions appropriately: is this Java or JavaScript? Also, what should happen if `SUB` isn't the same for two same studies? Or different `EXL`? Post your domain objects also or the data structures involved.

Comment: I remove tag as u suggested. Since `SUB` is not required for the next data so its not important. I need to get count and replace only `STU` and `EXL` is same for all data. I really appreciate if u help me with solution. Thanks.

Comment: if `EXL` is `false` on some item - should not it be considered?

Comment: No. As I mentioned in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop and `thisArg` optional parameter.

```js
var ar =  [{"STU":"Study1","SUB":"Subject1","EXL":"Yes"},{"STU":"Study1","SUB":"Subject1","EXL":"Yes"},{"STU":"Study2","SUB":"Subject1","EXL":"Yes"},{"STU":"Study3","SUB":"Subject1","EXL":"Yes"},{"STU":"Study1","SUB":"Subject1","EXL":"Yes"},{"STU":"Study3","SUB":"Subject1","EXL":"Yes"},{"STU":"Study3","SUB":"Subject1","EXL":"Yes"},{"STU":"Study2","SUB":"Subject1","EXL":"Yes"}]
var result = [];

ar.forEach(function(e) {
  if(!this[e.STU]) {
    this[e.STU] = {STU: e.STU, SUB : 0, EXL : e.EXL}
    result.push(this[e.STU]);
  }
  this[e.STU].SUB++;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Why the empty `{}` in the `.forEach()` call? Looks like this should have been [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead

Comment: It changes context of `this` from global to function context and in this case its object that you can use.

Comment: What I need to to modify these object into array. like `{0:'Study1 ',1:3:,2:'yes'}` and so on  instead of `{"STU":'Study1 ',"SUB":3',"EXL":'yes'}`

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to modify/change the input array in place - consider the following approach using `Array.sort` and `Array.splice` functions:

```
var arr =  [{"STU":"Study1","SUB":"Subject1","EXL":"Yes"},{"STU":"Study1","SUB":"Subject1","EXL":"Yes"},{"STU":"Study2","SUB":"Subject1","EXL":"Yes"},{"STU":"Study3","SUB":"Subject1","EXL":"Yes"},{"STU":"Study1","SUB":"Subject1","EXL":"Yes"},{"STU":"Study3","SUB":"Subject1","EXL":"Yes"},{"STU":"Study3","SUB":"Subject1","EXL":"Yes"},{"STU":"Study2","SUB":"Subject1","EXL":"Yes"}];

arr.sort((a,b) => a.STU.localeCompare(b.STU));
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0 || arr[i].STU !== arr[i-1].STU) {
        arr[i].SUB = 1;
    } else {
        arr[i-1].SUB++;
        arr.splice(i, 1);
        --i;
    }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4));
```

The output:

```
[
    {
        "STU": "Study1",
        "SUB": 3,
        "EXL": "Yes"
    },
    {
        "STU": "Study2",
        "SUB": 2,
        "EXL": "Yes"
    },
    {
        "STU": "Study3",
        "SUB": 3,
        "EXL": "Yes"
    }
]
```

Comment: What I need to to modify these object into array. like {0:'Study1 ',1:3:,2:'yes'} and so on instead of {"STU":'Study1 ',"SUB":3',"EXL":'yes'}

Comment: When transforming each nested object into array, each of them will look like `['Study1', 3, 'yes']`. Is that what you need?